# Missing instance data Datepicker while using iframe and jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

There are two versions of code. The first version is there is a main page containing an `iframe` and dialog `<div>`. The iframe will load the `dia.html` into the parent `<div id="popdiv">` and fire it as a dialog. The dialog itself will initiate a Datepicker with `elem.datepicker();`.

The second version is just the ideal version for what I want which is an `iframe` fire the parent main page dialog and have a Datepicker running. But this approach cannot load the `dia.html` page into the `<div id="popdiv">` which is not as handy.

My question:

1. Why is that when I want to select the element`$('#myInput', window.parent.document)` in the dia.html, I need to add window.parent.document after selector?

I try to figure it out by checking the html code in development tools. But I had no idea why it is required. How does query Dialog work?

2. How to make the `elem.datepicker();` inside the `dia.html` work inside the dialog if I want to use the `.load('dia.html')` approach? What was the reason it didn't work?

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-aOG0c6nPNzGk+5zjwyJaoRUgCdOrfSDhmMID2u4+OIslr0GjpLKo7Xm0Ao3xmpM4T8AmIouRkqwj1nrdVsLKEQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"
        integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="popdiv"></div>
    <iframe src="iframe1.html" height="800" width="800"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

iframe1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-aOG0c6nPNzGk+5zjwyJaoRUgCdOrfSDhmMID2u4+OIslr0GjpLKo7Xm0Ao3xmpM4T8AmIouRkqwj1nrdVsLKEQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"
        integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            alert('opening iframe');
            var parentDiv = $('#popdiv', window.parent.document);
            parentDiv.load('dia.html');
            parentDiv.dialog();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>iframe1</p>
</body>

</html>
```

dia.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-aOG0c6nPNzGk+5zjwyJaoRUgCdOrfSDhmMID2u4+OIslr0GjpLKo7Xm0Ao3xmpM4T8AmIouRkqwj1nrdVsLKEQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"
        integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            var elem = $('#myInput', window.parent.document);
            alert(elem.val());
            elem.datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Date: </p>
    <input id="myInput" value="22" />
</body>

</html>
```

working version

change it to not load html

iframe1.html (working)

```
        <script>
            $(function () {
                alert('opening iframe');
                var parentDiv = $('#popdiv', window.parent.document);
                //parentDiv.load('dia.html');
                parentDiv.dialog();
            });
        </script>
```

main.html (working)

```
   <div id="popdiv">
        <p>Date: </p>
        <input id="myInput" value="22" />
        <script>$('#myInput').datepicker();</script>
    </div>
```

Comment: The elements, `'#popdiv'` and `'#myInput'` do not exist in the DOM of the iFrame. this is why you need to include the proper parent in your Selector. Otherwise they will not be found.

Comment: Read through https://api.jquery.com/load/ *When calling `.load()` using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to `.html()` prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If `.load()` is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed.*